# What is the logic here with LINQ C# query?

Tags: c#, linq

Check the following program below from the book "Essential LINQ":

```
class Customer
    {
     public string CustomerID {get;set;}
     public string ContactName {get;set;}
     public string City {get;set;}
     public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
     {
        return new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {CustomerID = "ALFKI", ContactName = "Maria Anders", City = "Berlin"},
            new Customer {CustomerID = "ANATR", ContactName = "Sns Trujillo", City = "Mexico D.F."},
            new Customer {CustomerID = "ANTON", ContactName = "Antonio Moreno", City = "Mexico D.F."}
        };
     }
    }
void Main()
{
    var query = from c in Customer.GetCustomers()
                where c.City == "Mexico D.F."
                select new { c.City,  c.ContactName};
    foreach (var cityandcontact in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cityandcontact);
    }
}
```

In the LINQ Query, why it gives me error if I remove "new" from line:
`select new {c.City, c.ContactName};`

why we can't just write like this

```
select c.City, c.ContactName;
```

what is the logic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queries return enumerations of objects of the same class. It can be any class, but it needs to be just one for all rows. You cannot return pairs of objects (a city and a contact name) without combining them into a single object. In this case, you are combining them into an object of anonymous type, with two properties.

On a side note, there is no advantage to using `Select` method at all, because both properties come from the same `Customer` class. In fact, there is less efficient than returning customer objects unchanged, like this:

```
var query = from c in Customer.GetCustomers()
            where c.City == "Mexico D.F.";
foreach (var c in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", c.City, c.ContactName);
}
```

Comment: The first two lines makes it clear to me why we need to use anonymous types.

Comment: You still need the select since you're using the query syntax, you just don't need an anonymous object to hold the values.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the original objects can be used.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ methods, like other C# methods, can only return *one* value/object. (There is no syntax support added for said hypothetical construct to magically do what the `new { .. }` stuff does.)

This is why the different fields are "wrapped" in an new object: it is then a *single* value/object with *members* representing all the selected fields.

(Likewise, the final result, an `IEnumerable<..>`, is also just *one* value/object with 0 or more elements in the sequence: in this case each element is a new object created with `new { .. }` above.)

Answer (score 0):

`new { c.City,  c.ContactName};` is the C# syntax for an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

The 'select' selects a Customer class, which consists of a City variable and a ContactNamr variable. So, you have to provide select with a new class with those variables

Answer (score 0):

This is not SQL this is linq, and the syntax is basically what you see.

```
select new { c.City,  c.ContactName};
```

limits the output of the query to a type that contains just the City and the ContactName.

You may ask what type is this? Well it's an [anonymous type](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx&ei=Ykb6T97zF6ewiQepqZniBg&usg=AFQjCNHMvhwM6R1BXxYx5lUi_CPOLgC-EQ&sig2=G6FEnGGX3Wm3cdhdks89Zw) that the compiler creates for you.

The code then iterates over the results of the query (`IEnumerable<this_new_type>`) and writes the ToString() of this new type.

Answer (score 0):

select **new** is creating a new [anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

"Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first"

```
select new {c.City, c.ContactName};
```

You could also create a concrete class to project into.

i.e a class called **Blah**:

```
class Blah
{
  public string City {get;set;}
  public string ContactName {get;set;}
}

... [rest of query]
select new Blah {c.City, c.ContactName};
```

The reason you cannot go **"select c.City, c.ContactName;"**, is because the language syntax is not designed to handle it.